# loading every time static image in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

Hi have Static Image in a particular folder.

Based on my operation I am displaying the image.

Once i change the values and perform my task the same image will be displayed with new data.

I want to load the same image with new data when ever i perform my operation..

Kindly help me know how to load static image in a DIV of in a FRAME.

Comment: Can you add some code you tried? We are not giving you the solution for free. You have to add some code you tried and than can we help you improving it.  It looks you are new the stackoverflow so maybe you can take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this simple example:

```
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="changeIcon()">Click Me</button>
<br>
<div><img id="icon" src="http://mirrors.creativecommons.org/presskit/icons/share.large.png"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeIcon() {
    document.getElementById('icon').src = 'http://mirrors.creativecommons.org/presskit/icons/sa.large.png';
}   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```